# Weird bug which seems to be solved by adding a surplus line of code. Game of fifteen

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, integer

This is a puzzle game where in a 4x4 grid one has to arrange 15 numbered tiles in order.
Most of the scenarios, the program runs fine. However, when swapping the "1" digit to the nth row, n-2th column, the program seems to bug and duplicate the number 1.

Here's the catch. When I add a random line of code, say

```
int blah = 0;
```

or

```
printf("abc");
```

The problem just magically disappears.

Because I'm unable to locate the source of the problem, I'll have to post up the entirety of it.

To see the problem, run the code without any command line arguments, then enter 2 followed by 1.

When I added the random line of code at the end of my main() function, the problem just disappears. Please try it out, and help me find out what's happening; it's really confusing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n=4;
int win(int board[n][n]);
void print(int board[n][n]);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("No valid number accepted. Board size set as 4x4.\n");
    }
    else if(argc == 2)
    {
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
        if(n<2 || n>5)
        {
            printf("No valid number accepted. Board size set as 4x4.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Preparing board of size %dx%d\n",n,n);
        }
    }

    int board[n][n];
    printf("\n The aim of the game is to sort the board so that it runs in ascending order, from 1 to %d, from left to right and up to down starting from the top left square. To make a move, enter the number of the tile you want to move. No diagonal movement is allowed.\n\n",n*n-1);
    int c = n*n-1;
    for(int x = 0;x<n;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<n;y++)
        {
            board[x][y] = c;
            c--;
        }
    }
    if(n%2==0)
    {
        int temp1 = board[n-1][n-2];
        board[n-1][n-2] = board[n-1][n-3];
        board[n-1][n-3] = temp1;
    }
    print(board);
    int spacex = n-1;
    int spacey = n-1;
    char buffer[10];
    while(win(board) == 0)
    {
        printf("To move, enter the number you wish to move. Take note that this number must be adjacent to the blank space. Diagonal movement is not allowed.\nYour move: ");
        fgets(buffer,10,stdin);
        int move;
        char temp[20];
        if(sscanf(buffer," %d %s",&move,temp)!= 1)
        {
            printf("Enter a number please.\n");
            continue;
        }
        if(move == board[spacex+1][spacey])
        {
            board[spacex][spacey] = board[spacex+1][spacey];
            board[spacex+1][spacey] = 0;
            spacex++;
        }
        else if(move == board[spacex-1][spacey])
        {
            board[spacex][spacey] = board[spacex-1][spacey];
            board[spacex-1][spacey] = 0;
            spacex--;
        }
        else if(move == board[spacex][spacey+1])
        {
            board[spacex][spacey] = board[spacex][spacey+1];
            board[spacex][spacey+1] = 0;
            spacey++;
        }
        else if(move == board[spacex][spacey-1])
        {
            board[spacex][spacey] = board[spacex][spacey-1];
            board[spacex][spacey-1] = 0;
            spacey--;
        }
        else if(move == 0)
        {
            printf("Enter a valid digit please.\n");
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Enter a valid number please.\n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("\n");
        print(board);
    }
    printf("You won!\n");
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void print(int board[n][n])
{
    for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<n;y++)
        {
            if(board[x][y] == 0)
            {
                printf("__ ");
            }
            else
                printf("%2d ",board[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int win(int board[n][n])
{
    int check = 1;
    for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<n;y++)
        {
            if(board[x][y] != check)
            {
                if(x==n-1 && y == n-1);
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            check++;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Any other comments about the code would be greatly appreciated too. Thanks in advance!

Comment: At a quick glance: You try to check the adjacent tiles beyond the borders of the 15 puzzle. For example, when `spacex` is 0, you shouldn't test the tile to the left whose index is `spacex - 1`. (Actually, when you try it, you can wrap around the left and right borders.)

Comment: @M Oehm  Thank you for the answer, I did indeed exceed the boundaries of the array. However, what would be an explanation for the seemingly "fixed" problem when adding a random line of code?

Comment: @Quek - With undefined behavior *anything* can happen, including producing the expected output. There doesn't have to be any real explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is reading out of bounds.

These two variables point to the last elements of the array `board`:

```
   int spacex = n-1;
   int spacey = n-1;
```

but are used incorrectly in all if statements. whenever a +1 is used, they will read out of bounds or read an incorrect element:

```
if(move == board[spacex+1][spacey])
{
    board[spacex][spacey] = board[spacex+1][spacey];
    board[spacex+1][spacey] = 0;
    spacex++;
}
else if(move == board[spacex-1][spacey])
{ 
...
else if(move == board[spacex][spacey+1])
{
    board[spacex][spacey] = board[spacex][spacey+1];
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I didn't realise that. I would have to implement some form of bounds checking. However what would be an explanation for the seemingly "fixed" problem when i add in a random line of code?

Comment: @QuekYufei Undefined behavior. Until the code is correct, there is little point in discussing its behavior.